# UISearch bar keyboard color iphone monotouch

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, uikeyboard

How to change the `UISeachBar` keyboard color to the black ?

Answer (score 0):

The Short Answer is **NO** You can not change Color of KeyBoard Because Apple/iPhone does not provide any this type of  feature.

But you can change Appearance of keyboard, read [This official Document.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `keyboardAppearance` property of the text field to `UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert`. This gives a **black background**.

```
for(UIView *subView in searchBar.subviews)
    if([subView isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]])
        [(UITextField *)subView setKeyboardAppearance: UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
```